# infer type from function parameters

Tags: typescript

I have one array of functions, data will pass in each function from first to second, from second to third ... to last, it will work like pipe(), I create type that will verify that output of one function will coincide with input of next function

```js
type Hooks<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9> =
  [ (e: T1) => T2 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4, (e: T4) => T5 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4, (e: T4) => T5, (e: T5) => T6 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4, (e: T4) => T5, (e: T5) => T6, (e: T6) => T7 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4, (e: T4) => T5, (e: T5) => T6, (e: T6) => T7, (e: T7) => T8 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4, (e: T4) => T5, (e: T5) => T6, (e: T6) => T7, (e: T7) => T8, (e: T8) => T9 ];
```

but problem here is that is required to pass all types in generic

```js
const example: Hooks<number, string, boolean, never, never, never, never, never, never> = [
  e => e.toString(),
  (e: string) => Boolean(e),
];
```

Exist method to infer type from function argument ?

Something like

```js
type Hooks =
  [ (e: infer T1) => infer T2 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => infer T3 ]
  | [ (e: T1) => T2, (e: T2) => T3, (e: T3) => T4 ];   // of course this syntax not valid
```

or can be just method to send less generic arguments but with saving number of functions in array and ensure that each output will coincide with input of next function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic TypeScript type for an array of successive mapping functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762840/generic-typescript-type-for-an-array-of-successive-mapping-functions)

Comment: No, I search a type that can do it, don't a function

Comment: The problem is that types are not powerful enough to do this. The only option is using a generic function, which can `infer` types based on the arguments.

Comment: You can't infer generic type parameters from a value this way; if that's the question then it's a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69976058/2887218).  You have to use a helper function if you want to get the compiler to infer things like that; if you're okay with that I can write up an answer but it does seem to be a duplicate of the one TobiasS showed.  Which one is your question?

Comment: seems like it require declare type in each fn    const result = mappingSequence(23, [
  (a) => a * 60,
  (b) => 3,
  (c) => ({ duration: c }),
]);  // here duration is any

Comment: If you will accept a helper function: The only way to get the inference you want is to have one type parameter per function input.  Given that your `Hooks` type is already a large-ish finite collection of function types, you can get that inference with a similar large-ish finite collection of call signatures in the helper function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPR6ZN).  If that works for you I can write that up as an answer.  Let me know either way.

Comment: think yes, seems like is impossible to write a function that will receive an object that can have ~20 different Hooks list

Comment: So, do you want me to write up an answer or not?  Please "@jcalz" mention me if you want me to be notified.